# Associative array from PHP to Javascript using JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm trying to send an associative array from PHP to Javascript. But, for some reason, the output is Undefined. Here's the code:

**PHP (Suppositional array):**

```
$validationErrors = array("unregisteredName" => NULL,
"unregisteredEmail" => "Invalid e-mail", "unregisteredUsername" => NULL, 
"unregisteredPassword" => NULL);

$log = array("errors" => $validationErrors);
echo json_encode($log);
```

**Javascript:**

```
var addUserCallback = function(data) {
    if(data.errors && data.errors.length) {
        $.each(data.errors, function(index, error) {
            console.log(error);
            $("#"+index).attr("placeholder", error);
        });
    }
    else {
        window.location="/users/success/";
    }
};

var errorCallback = function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(arguments);
};

self.addUser = function() {
    var data = {
        unregisteredName: $("#unregisteredName").val(),
        unregisteredEmail: $("#unregisteredEmail").val(),
        unregisteredUsername: $("#unregisteredUsername").val(),
        unregisteredPassword: $("#unregisteredPassword").val()
    };
    $.post(addUserUrl, data).success(addUserCallback)
        .error(errorCallback);
}
```

And here is what I get from Chrome's Inspector:

**data:** `"↵{"errors":{"unregisteredName":null,"unregisteredEmail":"Invalid e-mail.","unregisteredUsername":null,"unregisteredPassword":null}}"`
**data.errors:** `Undefined`

So, what's happening is that, even getting data on "data" variable, because of the fact that it is unformatted it always redirects to the "success" page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Because `data` is a string.  You need to parse the JSON string and extract your object first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell jQuery to parse the JSON string.

```
$.post(addUserUrl, data, 'json').success(addUserCallback).error(errorCallback);
```

Though I usually pass the success callback to `$.post`

```
$.post(addUserUrl, data, addUserCallback, 'json').error(errorCallback);
```

Comment: Alternatively -- really, when not using jQuery AJAX as so -- look up "JSON.parse".

Comment: I also recommend setting application/json as the content type when you return JSON (that way jQuery might be able to figure it out without the datatype - but better do both).

Comment: WAY easier than I thought. I did tried to put "json" in `$.post`, but I was passing the success callback outside... Probably it wasn't understanding the parameters. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Falassion: You're welcome.  I've never used `.success`, I guess it acts differently.